# NetLogo: possible to select a patch by multiple criteria at one time step?

Tags: netlogo

This question is more theoretical then practical. My patches have variables `timber_value` and `harvest_cost`.

Please, is in NetLogo a way how to select a patch with maximum timber value and minimal harvest cost in one 'ask' i.e. at the same time? 
I imagine that could be solved by adding variable `difference` (`difference = timber_value - harvest_cost`) and simply select the patch by `ask max-one-of patches [difference]`.

However, I was wondering if there is another approach considering two variables (timber_value and harvest_cost) at the same time?

I can't really figure out better way then the one described...

Thank you for your shared knowledge and discussion !

Comment: Why not just use ask max-one-of patches [timber_value - harvest_cost]?

Comment: I really like that solution :) It still looks for the difference, but it is more ellegant ;-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the answer is no, but this has nothing to do with NetLogo.  To see the problem, create ordered pairs of values for the two attributes.  Suppose you get [2 1] and [1 2].  How do you want to compare them?  That said, you can get the largest timber value patches and then of them the lowest harvest cost patches.

```
patches-own [x y]

to test
  ca
  ask patches [
    set x random-float 1
    set y random-float 1
  ]
  show map [[list x y] of ?] 
    sublist
    sort-by compare patches
    0 10
end

to-report compare [#p1 #p2]
  let _x1 [x] of #p1
  let _x2 [x] of #p2
  let _y1 [y] of #p1
  let _y2 [y] of #p2
  report (_x1 < _x2) or (_x1 = _x2 and _y1 < _y2)
end
```

On the other hand, it seems in this case that you would be better off sorting by total profit.  Since this is just a real number, none of these sorting issues arise.

Comment: Wouldn't the general case just be the weighted absolute difference? w1 * _x1 - w2 * _x2? where w1 is the weight of x1's importance and w2 is the weight of x2?

Comment: @mattsap No, that's different than a lexicographic order.  However, it is more general than simple profit maximization (which is what I recommended at the end of my answer).